# How to set rails routes in response to verify domain name by add txt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Some Web ask me to add a text file in root to verify my owner.
But when add the text file in root

```
$filename.txt
```

rails error:

> No route matches [GET] "/filename.txt"

Then what I did is add the following line under Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/filename.txt'
```

then error:

```
Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes.
```

I don't know what most verification domain name expect to get return, as rails strictly controller how to access through the routes.
Help need Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the file in the `public` directory.

Comment: It shown "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." which might be ok, I am checking with the web if it verified. There are several files like 404.html or 500.html shown the same message.

Comment: When I checked with chrome inspect: the file I add and existing 404 or 500 has no error. So I believed it work and now for me another knowledge of rails!